# How to install unix ubunto on windows 10 computer

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am new to linux I have laptop with windows 10 installed can I make dual boots  one in windows and another in linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do that easily, to do this follow theese steps:
1.Download the ubuntu ISO file from ubuntu.com
2.Download "Rufus", This is a app that helps you format a flash drive
3.Format the disk using Rufus and Boot into your Bios(Just search The Internet On How to boot over usb)
4.Setup linux as usual
5. At the disk portion select install alongside windows
Done!
Comment if you have any questions.